# 400 Bad Request response in JMeter while request works on Postman and SOAP UI

Tags: http, testing, jmeter

So i am trying to test a http request from jmeter, my payload is in json format and i have also made sure to give all the headers that i am giving post man, yet the issues does not resolve and it gives me the following error
[image: ERROR RESPONSE IN JMETER]
when i use this same http request from soapui or postman it works fine, i have double checked my end point as it is the same. adding screen shots for refrence.
[image: JMETER REQUEST HEADERS]
[image: POSTMAN HEADERS]

I tried to change and add headers in my header manager check the java version and all those points. even in a negative case i am not able to capture the complete response on jmeter by response i mean 403 not authorized response while the same is being captured on postman

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP 400 status code description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 `Bad Request` response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (for example, malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

So most probably something is wrong with your request payload, maybe it's malformed somehow or it's a copy-paste issue.

Be informed that you can just convert your Postman request to JMeter by recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

1. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will create appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). You should be able to replay your request either right away or after [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/convert-postman-api-tests)